# In what sense is the standard hyperbolic metric on the poincare upper half plane canonical?

Tags: number-theory, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

On the Poincare upper half plane, the standard hyperbolic is given by $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$.

In what sense is this metric canonical? E.g., why don't people use $2ds^2$? or $3ds^2$?

Answer (score 3):

That's the metric that gives constant Gaussian curvature of $-1$.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but isn't it just *a* metric that gives a constant Gaussian curvature of $-1$? We could just as well choose its pullback by an arbitrary nontrivial diffeomorphism of the upper half plane.

Comment: We also want it to respect the complex structure: it should be a multiple of $-i\,dz\,d\bar z$ in local coordinates. @Kajelad

Comment: does scaling the metric change the curvature? What's the curvature of $ads^2$?

Comment: Is it $-1/a$ or $-1/a^2$? Can't remember. Anyway, does increasing the radius of a balloon change its curvature? @stupid_question_bot

Comment: The units of curvature are "inverse area". So, if you replace $ds^2$ by $a \, ds^2$, thus multiplying area by a factor of $a$, the effect is to multiply curvature by a factor of $1/a$.

Answer (score 2):

This metric is the only one (up to scaling by a real)precerved by the action of $Sl_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then you take the scaling to have a curvature constant to $-1$.

Why are we looking at the action of $Sl_2(\mathbb{R})$ ? To understand this, one have to show that the only bijective holomorphic map from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ are $f_(a,b,c,d): z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc=1$ and $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{C}^4$. This is a classical exercise.

Now we want holomorphic bijection from $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{H}$. This impose $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

Finnaly a another exercice show that $ds$ is the only metric invariant by this maps.